# Is it possible to see if vivado inferred blockram?

Tags: vivado, synthesis

I have a following piece of code:

```
module cw305_reg_aes #(
   parameter pADDR_WIDTH = 21,
   parameter pBYTECNT_SIZE = 14,
   parameter pPK_WIDTH = 800 // 800 * 8
)(
   input  wire                                  usb_clk,
   input  wire                                  crypto_clk,
   input  wire [pADDR_WIDTH-pBYTECNT_SIZE-1:0]  reg_address,

   input  wire [pBYTECNT_SIZE-1:0]              reg_bytecnt,

   output reg  [7:0]                            read_data,
   input  wire [7:0]                            write_data,
   input  wire                                  reg_read,
   input  wire                                  reg_write,

   output wire [7:0]                            reg_pk
);

reg  [7:0]                   reg_read_data;
reg  [7:0]                   reg_crypt_public_key [pPK_WIDTH-1:0];
(* ASYNC_REG = "TRUE" *) reg  [7:0] reg_crypt_public_key_crypt [pPK_WIDTH-1:0];

always @(posedge crypto_clk) begin
   for (i=0; i<pPK_WIDTH;i=i+1) begin
      reg_crypt_public_key_crypt[i] <= reg_crypt_public_key[i];
   end   
end

assign reg_pk = reg_crypt_public_key_crypt[0]

always @(*) begin
   if (reg_read) begin
      case (reg_address)          
         `REG_CRYPT_PUBLIC_KEY:      reg_read_data = reg_crypt_public_key[reg_bytecnt];
         default:                    reg_read_data = 0;
      endcase
   end
   else
      reg_read_data = 0;
end

always @(posedge usb_clk) begin
   if (reg_write) begin
      case (reg_address)
         `REG_CRYPT_PUBLIC_KEY:      reg_crypt_public_key[reg_bytecnt] <= write_data;
      endcase
   end
end
```

How can I see if Vivado 2021.1 inferred block ram instead of distributed ram for the `reg_crypt_public_key` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block rams are reported in the synthesis log. If BRAMs are inferred there will be a section detailing what parts of the HDL produced which BRAMs of how many ports, width, etc

It reads like the log mentioned on the forums here: https://support.xilinx.com/s/article/61027?language=en_US
With header like

```
|Module Name   ------     | RTL Object | PORT A (depth X width)   | W | R | PORT B (depth X width)  | W | R | OUT_REG      | RAMB18 | RAMB36 | Hierarchical Name
```

Additionally opening the final utilization report will show a hierarchical break down of where in the design is using BRAMs vs LUTs as memory (distributed).

Finally see the synthesis guide for how to intentionally infer BRAM per the manufacturers recommended code guidelines. p. 111 https://www.xilinx.com/content/dam/xilinx/support/documents/sw_manuals/xilinx2021_2/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf

Comment: Thanks, it seems my move from big widths to arrays of bytes has reduced my memory usage so much that I don't need block ram anymore. It moved it all to D-RAM. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

- Open the post route design or dcp file in the Vivado GUI.
- Locate the netlist window and surf the hierarchical path to expected BRAM path.
- Right click 'schematic' on the design element in the netlist window.
- The schematic viewer opens showing: inferred BRAM, distributed RAM or registers.

Here is a little example showing a register connected to a BRAM:
[image]

This is a general way you can explore what the tools have done with the RTL code.